# Find out which Homebrew formula gave a shared library file

Tags: homebrew, package-management

I installed Homebrew cask package [sequel-pro](https://www.sequelpro.com), but when I try to use it, it complains in a dialog about a failing `dlopen()` naming the shared library (`/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so`).

I think this is maybe a missing dependency, and requires reporting, but my first question is:

*Is there a way to find which Homebrew formula provides a missing shared library not found in my system?*

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180898/6995250) answers your question.

Comment: It sure gives good hints about the particular Sequel Pro problem, in case somebody is interested. TLDR: Sequel Pro has not seen new release since 2016, and is not recently updated even in the master branch. It is possible to make it work by altering the MySQL authentication method or by creating a dedicated user for Sequel Pro, but probably longer term solution is to find a replacement for the whole thing.